# ASP.NET MVC: how to include <span> in link from Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need the text of a link wrapped with `<span>` as in:

```
<a href="/foo.html"><span>Edit Group</span></a>
```

Can I do that with Html.ActionLink?  This doesn't work:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("<span>Edit Group</span>", "Edit", New With {.id = "bar"})%>
```

It just HTML encodes the `<` and `>` as `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Is there a simple solution, or should I build the links by hand with Url.Action?

This is for use with jQuery-UI Tabs.  Tab labels need to be wrapped in `<span>` to get animation when AJAX content is loading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to do it with `Url.Action`, there's no way with `Html.ActionLink` as far as I know.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the Url.Action helper method as a workaround (in case no other answers better fit your needs).

For example, the following can be in marked up in your view:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("Edit", 
                        New With {.id = "bar"}) %>">
 <span>Edit Group</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, that's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 9):

You can also roll your own HtmlHelper Extension Method, I actually prefer this method as you can control the placement of ids, classes, and other attributes like a title.

Here is a [blog post](http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2010/10/09/How-To-Create-Custom-MVC-Extension-Methods.aspx) that I put together on the subject.

Comment: This is awesome. But honestly [Razor team](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/248) need to realize that there is a fair demand for this sort of customization in link, and they should consider providing an option for `Raw( _ )` rendering in action link.

Comment: Have you looked into TagHelpers? http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Create-your-own-Domain-Specific-Language-in-ASPNET-with-TagHelpers

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple helperExtension example that worked for me:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1702210/4518688.aspx/1?Re+Quick+question+about+Ajax+ActionLink+and+span

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
@{
   var link = Html.ActionLink("{0}", "Edit", New {id = "bar"}).ToString();
   var url = string.Format(link, "<span>Edit Group</span>");
}

@Html.Raw(url);
```

//NICE HACK: Recommend using previous advice and write a helper to wrap this up.