# Add span tage to ActionLink title

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to add a span tag to the title of an actionlink to output the following html

```
<li><a href="#" id="topmenu1" accesskey="1" title=""><span>Homepage</span></a></li>
```

I currently have

```
<li><%= Html.ActionLink("Homepage", "Index", "Home", null, new { @id= "topmenu1" , @accesskey = "1", @title = "" } ) %></li>
```

which gives me

```
<li><a accesskey="1" href="/" id="topmenu1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
```

without the span tag around Homepage

I cannot use

```
<span>Homepage</span>
```

as the title variable of the actionlink, that doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC: how to include <span> in link from Html.ActionLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547097/asp-net-mvc-how-to-include-span-in-link-from-html-actionlink)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASP.NET MVC: how to include <span> in link from Html.ActionLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547097/asp-net-mvc-how-to-include-span-in-link-from-html-actionlink)

Comment: I did a search but obviously missed that questions. Thanks