# Misalignment of Navigation menu

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating a navigation menu using bootstrap. This navigation menu is built for my MVC 5 application. The Admin menu needs to fixed in terms of alignment. If you notice the Admin menu and its gyphicon image is not aligned as other menu items. I had changed the menu item to use html.action link as that is the recommended way of implementing navigation links in MVC.

**Navigation Menu**

[image]

**Html**

```
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#"><img src="~/Images/Computacenter.png" /> </a>
                    <h1>MCR</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Home</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Requests</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Activities</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Reports</p></a></li>
                        <li class="hideli"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Team", "Admin", null, null)  </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Save View</p></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-header img {
    max-height: 55px;
    max-width: 55px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.navbar-header h1 {
    float: left;
    color: darkblue;
}

.navbar-search select {
    position: relative;
    left: 84px;
}


.nav navbar-nav navbar-right {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav > li {
    background-color: white;
}

.nav > li a:hover > .glyphicon {
    color: #009ddc;
}


.nav li:hover p {
    color: #009ddc;
}

.hideli {

    padding-right: 200px;
}
```

**The elements that get rendered on page load**

[image]

Comment: may be you can take some help from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547097/asp-net-mvc-how-to-include-span-in-link-from-html-actionlink

Comment: That example shows the use of url.action and what i need is html.action as i want to generate the action tag

Comment: I think the alignment that you want is not possible with html.action so use url.action instead

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the code

```
<li class="hideli"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Team", "Admin", null, null)  </li>
```

with

```
<li class="hideli"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Team", "Admin", null, null) </p></a> </li>
```

Comment: This isnt correct as @Html.ActionLink generates an anchor tag. With your code two anchor tags are generated

Comment: I see only 1 anchor tag in developer tools

Comment: Hi Shiva thats with my code. With your code it shows two